# Why does my HSQLDB table take seemingly way too much space on the disk?

Tags: hsqldb

I have the following HSQLDB schema:

```
CREATE TABLE RUNSTATS
(
   ID      BINARY(16)   NOT NULL,
   ENTITY  BLOB(128K)     NOT NULL
   ,CHECK (PUBLIC.RUNSTATS.ID IS NOT NULL)
   ,CHECK (PUBLIC.RUNSTATS.ENTITY IS NOT NULL)
);

ALTER TABLE RUNSTATS
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_runstats
   PRIMARY KEY (ID);

CREATE TABLE RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX
(
   ID          BINARY(16),
   TIMESTAMP   BIGINT,
   FLOWID      VARCHAR(200),
   AVGLATENCY  DOUBLE
);

ALTER TABLE RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX
   ADD CONSTRAINT pk_runstats__avglatencyindex
   PRIMARY KEY (ID, FLOWID);

CREATE INDEX IDX_RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX_FLOWID
   ON RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX (FLOWID ASC);
```

The RUNSTATS table is in the **x.lobs** file and the RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX - in the **x.data**

I insert RunStats objects, where each yields 1 row in the RUNSTATS table and 100 rows in the RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX. I run three sessions, inserting 100, 1000 and 10000 RunStats objects.

Another very important detail - actual FLOWID values are all exactly 20 English characters long, despite the field being VARCHAR(200)

Please, find below the disk usage summary of the **x.data** file (containing the RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX table):

1. 10,000 rows = 2.0MB
2. 100,000 rows = 16MB
3. 1,000,000 rows = 128MB

Now the raw calculation:
 (sizeOf(ID) + sizeOf(FLOWID) + sizeOf(TIMESTAMP) + sizeOf(AVGLATENCY)) = 16 + 20 + 8 + 8 = 52

So 1,000,000 rows should take about 52 * 1,000,000 = ~50MB

The optimal size is more than twice less than the actual.

Is it a normal database overhead? Can I instruct the hsqldb engine to utilize the space more efficiently?

A bit more context:

- Entities are only added (never deleted)
- There is a well defined period when the entities are added at a regular pace. For instance, every 10 seconds for 3 days. After that - no more entities are added.

**EDIT**

Please, find the compressed script file here - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2pbsdBJxJI3Z2dFTndMZnBMU2c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inserted 1,000,000 rows into the RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX table and the size of the .data file was 128MB. The extra size is due to the primary key and the extra index on the table (32 bytes) and the lengths of the row, strings and nullability information. The FLOWID column uses 20 + 5 bytes. In total, each row needs 32 + 12 + 4 bytes extra space, so the total is 100 bytes. This is scaled up to a multiple of 32 bytes (FILE SCALE) resulting in 128 bytes per row.

Check your .script file. If you have `SET FILE SCALE 256` or higher, this may explain the extra space. The size of each row is a multiple of this SCALE value.

With the default SCALE 32, and the given size of the FLOWID, each row should use 128 bytes.

You can also perform SHUTDOWN COMPACT on the database and see what the size is, after the deleted rows have been removed.

You have added a link to a .script file. The `SET TABLE ...` statement indicates 751700 rows in the large table. Each row takes 128 bytes on disk.

```
SET FILES SCALE 32
...
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.RUNSTATS(ID BINARY(16) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,ENTITY BLOB(128K) NOT NULL)
CREATE CACHED TABLE PUBLIC.RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX(ID BINARY(16),TIMESTAMP BIGINT,FLOWID VARCHAR(200),AVGLATENCY DOUBLE,PRIMARY KEY(ID,FLOWID))
CREATE INDEX IDX_RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX_FLOWID ON PUBLIC.RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX(FLOWID)
...
SET TABLE PUBLIC.RUNSTATS INDEX '4021 0 7517'
SET TABLE PUBLIC.RUNSTATS__AVGLATENCYINDEX INDEX '4039 79 0 0 751700'
```

Comment: The rows where only added, nothing was deleted. But I ran SHUTDOWN COMPACT - no effect, as expected. I can see `SET FILES SCALE 32` in the script file.

Comment: Perhaps you have other tables, or the tables are larger. Check the .script file for `SET TABLE xxx INDEX nn nn nn` statements. The last number is the row count for the table.

Comment: You are right, stupid me. There is one more table. I am going to remove it from the schema, rerun the whole test and then update the question.